# Teradata partitioning sequential events

Tags: teradata, partition

Teradata - Below are two rail cars arriving at a station. 773 is emptied (RI/RE) and then loaded (RI/RL) then departs TD. 819 is only emptied and then departs. I'd like to create the results below this table. I've tried using case statement grouping on car but the same car has multiple trips through stations and so max and min give me unpredictable results. I have read up on partition but I am having difficulty visualizing this. Any help is appreciated.

*Note: it would be optimal to limit the initial search to EVT_CD='TA' AND STN=DEST to eliminate any cars that simply pass through a station. But I can't limit the entire recordset to that because TDs have a different destination.

```
CAR_NUMB    EVT_DT  EVT_TM  EVT_CD  EVST_CD WB_ID   STN     DEST
773 03/08/2016  19.05.00    TA          582016  BOSTON      BOSTON  
773 03/12/2016  04.04.00    AP  PU      582016  BOSTON      BOSTON  
773 03/12/2016  14.35.00    RI  RE      412016  BOSTON      BOSTON  
773 03/12/2016  14.37.00    AP  PL      412016  BOSTON      BOSTON  
773 03/12/2016  14.45.00    RI  RL      812016  BOSTON      HOUSTON 
773 03/14/2016  12.22.00    TD          812016  BOSTON      HOUSTON 
819 03/04/2016  17.50.00    TA          362016  STLOUIS     STLOUIS  
819 03/06/2016  13.50.00    AP  PU      362016  STLOUIS     STLOUIS  
819 03/06/2016  17.27.55    RI  RE      042016  STLOUIS     STLOUIS  
819 03/07/2016  00.37.00    RI  PR      042016  STLOUIS     PORTLAND
819 03/11/2016  01.47.00    TD          042016  STLOUIS     PORTLAND     

Desired output: 
CAR_NUMB    TA              AP          RIRE        RIRL        TD
773 03/08/2016 19.05.00 03/12/20..  03/12/20..  03/12/20..  03/14/2016  12.22.00
819 03/04/2016 17.50.00 03/06/20..  03/06/20..      null    03/11/2016 01.47.00
```

the [..] above. I cut off the time stamp for formatting.

Comment: What's your Teradata release? "*the same car has multiple trips through stations*" = there might be another group of rows for the same `CAR_NUMB`/`DEST` combination? What's the maximum number of rows between `TA` and `TD`

Comment: Release: 15.00.0501  15.00.05.01. And yes a car may make many round trips from BOSTON to HOUSTON and back again. Sometimes the round trip will take 7 days or it could take 2 months so the car/dest combination (which is what I've been using combined with a manual error correction) fails a high enough percentage of time to be a problem. Using Max aggregates with evt dates can yield a car departing a yard before it arrives if there's a TD event a week earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for the minimum date/time for a given `EVT_CD` within the next 5 rows using `CASE` using a Windowed Aggregate Function.

I combine date and time to Timestamps as it's easier to work with:

```
SELECT tab.*
  ,CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND) AS TA
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'AP'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_NUMB
         ORDER BY EVT_DT, EVT_TM
         ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS AP
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'RI' AND EVST_CD = 'RE'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_NUMB 
         ORDER BY EVT_DT, EVT_TM
         ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS RIRE
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'RI' AND EVST_CD = 'RL'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_NUMB 
         ORDER BY EVT_DT, EVT_TM
         ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS RIRL
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'TD'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_NUMB 
         ORDER BY EVT_DT, EVT_TM
         ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS TD
FROM tab
QUALIFY -- finally return only the starting row
   EVT_CD = 'TA'
```

If the number of rows between `TA` and `TD` can be greater than 5 you must adjust the `ROWS` accordingly. If the number varies a lot and there are missing `EVT_CD` this approach might fail and report data from the next trip. This problem can be fixed by adding another step:

```
SELECT 
   CAR_NUMB
  ,TA
  ,CASE WHEN   AP < TD THEN AP END AS AP
  ,CASE WHEN RIRE < TD THEN RIRE END AS RIRE
  ,CASE WHEN RIRL < TD THEN RIRL END AS RIRL
  ,TD
FROM
 (
   previous query
 ) AS dt
```

If `TD` might be missing you can go for a different approach: Find the previous `TA` timestamp and group by it:

```
SELECT 
   CAR_NUMB
  ,TA
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'AP'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) AS AP
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'RI' AND EVST_CD = 'RE'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) AS RIRE
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'RI' AND EVST_CD = 'RL'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) AS RIRL
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'TD'
            THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
       END) AS TD
FROM
 (
   SELECT tab.*
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN EVT_CD = 'TA'
               THEN CAST(EVT_DT AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + (EVT_TM - TIME '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND)
          END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_NUMB
            ORDER BY EVT_DT, EVT_TM
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS TA
   FROM tab
   -- maybe QUALIFY TA IS NOT NULL?
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY
   CAR_NUMB
  ,TA
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, you rock. I'll play with this today and see if I can get it to work. I did simplify my example data above for brevity. In reality there can be 20-30 events between a TA and TD. Switches, track orders, etc.  In the end I may have to brute force this with script loops but I'm going to give partitions the old college try first. This was really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. I tried to upvote this but I don't have enough rep points yet. So please upvote whoever reads this.

Comment: @CalHarris: The 2nd query should work with any combination/number of rows between two `TA`...